# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to run a query but not sure whether it is supported, the problem I face is I want to pass a list in the query. I have some joins too in the query, the query fails with the message:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on.

How can I make this work?

```java
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery(
   " SELECT s,c from Sow s left join ChildSow c " + 
   "  inner join Project p on p.projectId = s.projectId on s.employeeId = c.employeeId " + 
   "  and s.projectId = c.correctProjectId ");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object> list =  query.getResultList();
em.close();
```

```
9:56:35.195 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:211: unexpected token: on
19:56:35.204 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:211: unexpected token: on
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: on
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3273)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2930)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2697)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2653)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.Hql
```

Comment: Please remove not related to the problem commented code. Please also provide a full stacktrace.

Comment: Added it as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your query in the following way:

```java
List<Object[]>  result = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT s, c from Sow s left join ChildSow c " + 
    "inner join Project p on p.projectId = s.projectId " + 
    "where s.employeeId = c.employeeId and s.projectId = c.correctProjectId",
Object[].class).getResultList();

result.forEach(row -> {
   Sow sow =  (Sow) row[0];
   ChildSow childSow = (ChildSow) row[1];
   // ...
});
```

Please note that when your query uses multiple [root entity references](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-root-reference) you will obtain result as a list of `Object[]`.